# Arduino Twitters

Tags: arduino, twitter

I'm looking for a list of cool projects that people have made with the arduino that twitter...i have read about plants that tweet when they need watering or pets who have a button to let you know when they are hungry....whole houses which twitter the power usage etc....

So is there a place to go for a list of these....? Or could people just link the individual projects here.

Comment: You are asking for "cool" projects, but yet you want devices that send tweets.  Does not compute!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Botanicalls](http://www.botanicalls.com/kits/) is a open project that takes time working.
You can buy the kit and assemble or otherwise you have [all information](http://www.botanicalls.com/archived%5Fkits/twitter/) on the web to build and why not make improvements?

The project where arduino is a twitter notification as better success at marketing today is [BakerTweet](http://www.bakertweet.com/). This is a funny device where the baker select that product just out of the oven and this is published in twitter. 
What to does this serve? Those who do not live in town many times when we go to buy bread bakers are selling day-old bread. By this we know when we can go for fresh bread, cakes, buns, croissants, ... ;)

Another open project is the [Tweet a Watt](http://www.ladyada.net/make/tweetawatt/), this project is very interesting and useful because we can monitor the consumption of a device by the Twitter. From my point of view is an expensive project, but with a little imagination we can reduce cost if we are forced.

[Oficial Tiwitter library](http://www.arduino.cc/playground/Code/TwitterLibrary)

Silly projects (my point of view ;) ):
[Bubblino](http://www.mcqn.com/bubblino)
[KickBee](http://portfolio.menscher.com/itp/kickbee/)

Answer (score 2):

Here, play around with mine.  http://ka1kjz.com/?p=129

You'll need to Base64 encode your username and password, there are plenty of sites to do that, just google around, you'll see the line in the code where you need to stick it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do a lot of cool things by having devices twitter programmatically.  I had a server configured to twitter it's uptime and disk usage.  A couple ideas:

- Twitter status of coffee pot in a nearby kitchen/breakroom
- Room temperature
- Weekly rainfall
- Cat entrances/exits from the building
- toilet flushes
- Daily electricity usage.

A pile of neat stuff!

Answer (score 2):

Baker Tweet is a nice arduino / Twitter project: http://www.bakertweet.com/

Answer (score 1):

The next upgrade to my [Chaos Machine Controller](http://chaos.trader.name/accessories/chaos-controller/) will have a webserver and Twitter updates, so that anyone who's interested in the Chaos Machine can keep track of how long the machine has been running, and how many balls have passed through the machine during the installation.

Answer (score 1):

I have a twittering home monitoring system, it also logs to Pachube. I am constantly upgrading this and expect to have more tweets and also SMS over the next few weeks.

Block diagram of system:

[image]

Arduino code [here](http://john.crouchley.com/blog/archives/404).