# How to connect the Arduino with Twitter via GSM/GPRS?

Tags: arduino, gsm

I know there are tons of projects that use WIFI or simple LAN shields to send sensor data from the Arduino as Twitter messages. How could this work with a mobile phone connection? Are there libraries or handware layers that enable TCP via GSM or GPRS? If not with Twitter, could I email the data or send to other APIs which would be HTTP requests?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get a [gsm/gprs module from sparkfun](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/9533).  It looks like that'd be pretty easy to get going.  You would, of course, need data service to run it.

Answer (score 2):

Along with what Dustin stated take a look at [Arduino Twitter Examples](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/133/arduino-twitters) for possible ideas or inspiration.

Answer (score 2):

I connected an Arduino to a Telit GM862 (GPRS/GPS) module. It's a breadboard setup but I know that shields are coming for these modules.
There is a bit of code the lets you connect to twitter via GPRS. Not really a library but maybe a starting point.
http://tinkerlog.com/2009/05/15/interfacing-arduino-with-a-telit-gm862/

Answer (score 0):

I found a shield that uses a virtual serial port to communicate to the modem. I think the store is from Chile, here is the link [Arduino GM862 Shield](http://www.olimex.cl/product_info.php?products_id=733).

[image]